# PHP selecting next array value of same id within the same page

Tags: php

Sorry if I asked a dumb question, quite new to PHP. I wanted to select the next array value within the same page and the same `id`, as all of them are from the same `id`. Mind if I ask for any help on this code? Thanks!

```
<?php
//get the id from the view page / search page e.g. url?id=1
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    include "backend/connect.php";
    $sqlquestion = "Select * from game_question where game_id_fk = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlquestion);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0){
    echo "<script>alert('No questions found!');</script>";
}
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $question[] = $row['game_question'];
    $qid[] = $row['game_question_id'];
}
?>
<?php
    $current_index = array_search($qid, $question);

    $next = $current_index + 1;
    $prev = $current_index - 1;
?>
<?php if ($prev > 0): ?>
<a href="<?= $id[$prev] ?>">Previous</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($next < count($question)): ?>
<a href="<?= $id[$next] ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[This is the table schema of game_question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26xjR.png)

Comment: Are you trying to implement the Next and Previous functionality?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm trying to navigate the questions one by one using the next previous functionality

Comment: I think you might have to show your table schema to get help with this problem.

Comment: Edited with the table schema attached, i apologize if I did things wrong

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**
*Concatenating query params into query string may lead to SQL injection, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)*

A simple way to do that is to implement some sort of pagination, in which each page is exactly 1 item long, and pass the current page as a `GET` param.
You can implement it as a `LIMIT` clause on your query, like this:

```
$pos = (isset($_GET['pos']) && $_GET['pos']) ? $_GET['pos'] : 0;
$sqlquestion = "
    Select * 
    from game_question 
    where game_id_fk = $id 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET $pos
";
```

Then you have to calculare previous and next position based on the $pos variable and add them in the links as a query param, like `url.php?id=1&pos=3`;

*Note that this way positions starts at 0*

Answer (score 0):

I would take an approach of querying the DB only once, so i assume the amount of questions belonging to one `id` is not too huge.

This way you can retrieve all the results and then use some front end magic to display these results with next/prev functionality. I wrote a sample where jQuery has your questions, so its up to you how you want to display them.

You can also look at Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/), it has some cool features, so you could get PHP to loop your questions and write the HTML elements, then Bootstrap would do its magic displaying it

I've also added parameter binding to your query, this will prevent some SQL injections and should always be used

```
<?php
    //get the id from the view page / search page e.g. url?id=1
    $id = $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
    include "backend/connect.php";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM game_question WHERE game_id_fk = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $questions = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0){
        echo "<script>alert('No questions found!');</script>";
        die;
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $questions[$row['game_question_id']] = $row['game_question'];
    }
?>
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var questions = <?php echo json_encode($questions) ?>;

$.each(questions, function (i, elem) {
    // do your stuff
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Here's an example of bootstrap tabs with prev/next buttons: https://codepen.io/techiegang/pen/QjdgJJ